# Trying to plot confusion matrix, but I find this error: Singleton array 23 cannot be considered a valid collection

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

I'm tying to plot a confusion matrix of a Neural Network, I already constructed and saved the model. I have 11 labels in my dataset.
I using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

rounded_labels = np.argmax(y_test, axis=-1) #y_test are the test label, I use np.argmax to find an integer

test_model = load_model('/model.h5')

y_pred = test_model.predict(X_test, steps=1, verbose=0)

rounded_y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1) #I use np.argmax to find an integer prediction
```

And when I print rounded_y_pred I find some integer number from 0 to 10, it seems good because I have eleven labels but when I try to print the confusion matrix:

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true=rounded_labels, y_pred=rounded_y_pred)
```

I find this error: **TypeError: Singleton array 23 cannot be considered a valid collection.**
I really don't know how to fix it. Could someone help me? Thank you so much

Comment: Please specify in the text and in the tags the library you're using

Comment: I'm using sklearn.metrics import classification_report

Comment: - Are your sure both `rounded_labels` and `rounded_y_pred` are array-like of shape `(n_samples,)` ?

- Have you checked that rounded_labels is also an array of integers between 0 and 10 ? If y_test is not one-hot encoded for instance (if it is already the list of labels that you're trying to put in rounded_labels), then your rounded_labels is only the index of a sample of the highest class, which could explain the "23"...

- See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231018/7456923 : does it work if you remove "y_true=" and "y_pred=" in your function call ? (seems weird, but who knows...)

Comment: I found this error! I have to delete rounded_labels and put directly y_test. Thank you so much